# Pythonでのグラフ作成方法

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

グループ× 商品 別に購入数を集計した数表（下記df）があります。

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   '購入数A': [150, 300, 100, 50, 300],
                   '購入数B': [500, 900, 350, 100, 300],
                   '購入数C': [1000, 390, 100, 300, 300],
                   '購入数D': [800, 400, 370, 800, 100],
                   '購入数E': [200, 50, 500, 350, 300]})
df
```

この集計表から、２種のグラフを作成したいと考えています。

1. グループごとに、商品ごとの購入数を棒グラフで可視化

   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. グループ× 商品 別の購入数

   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のようにseabornを使って描画する方法を試したりしていますが、
複数列の集計値をひとつのグラフにどのようにまとめて描画できるかがわかりません。

```
a = df.query('Group == "A"')
sns.barplot(y='購入数A', data=a)
```

こちらご存じの方、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

---

追記（アドバイスいただいた内容をアレンジしたコードです）

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

matplotlib.rc('font', family='MS Gothic')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   '購入数A': [150, 300, 100, 50, 300],
                   '購入数B': [500, 900, 350, 100, 300],
                   '購入数C': [1000, 390, 100, 300, 300],
                   '購入数D': [800, 400, 370, 800, 100],
                   '購入数E': [200, 50, 500, 350, 300]})
display(df)

test = df.melt(id_vars='Group', var_name='購入数')
display(test)

sns.barplot(x='購入数', y='value', hue='Group',
            data=df.melt(id_vars='Group', var_name='購入数'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの記事の応用で出来そうです。
[How to make a plot with multiple bars using seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57046439/9014308)

こんな感じでしょうか。

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

matplotlib.rc('font', family='MS Gothic')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   '購入数A': [150, 300, 100, 50, 300],
                   '購入数B': [500, 900, 350, 100, 300],
                   '購入数C': [1000, 390, 100, 300, 300],
                   '購入数D': [800, 400, 370, 800, 100],
                   '購入数E': [200, 50, 500, 350, 300]})

df = df.set_index('Group')

sns.barplot(x='購入数', y='value', hue='Group',
            data=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Group', var_name='購入数'))

plt.show()
```

タイトルとかラベルとかの細かい調整は、この記事が参考になるかも。

[seabornの細かい見た目調整をあきらめない](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/7fee4dd35c6d42e0ebae)

---

コメントを受けて追記：

参考にした記事で`barplot`の`data`パラメータ指定時に`df.reset_index().melt()`としていたので、それを変更せずに対処しようとして`df = df.set_index('Group')`を入れましたが、`reset_index()`を使わなければ`set_index()`は不要でした。

Comment: ありがとうございます！.meltで縦持ちに変換してから作図する発想がありませんでした。。meltも初めて知ったのでdocument確認しましたが、value_vars=['購入数A', '購入数B'] 等で縦持ち変換する列を選択することもできるのですね！ちなみに、1点追加で教えてください。一度set_indexをかませる理由は何かございますか？？その1行を入れずに、sns.barplot(x='購入数', y='value', hue='Group', data=df.melt(id_vars='Group', var_name='購入数')) と、ダイレクトにグラフ作成することもできるのかなと考えたのですが、認識誤りありますでしょうか？？

Comment: 最初にそれを試してダメだったので、おそらく`Group`を`index`に変えれば出来るかと思ってやってみたら出来た、という手順でやってます。

Comment: あれ、そうでしたか、、。私がテストした結果を、トップに追記したのですが、こちらでよさそうですが、エラー出てしまいますか？？可能でしたらテストいただけるとありがたいです！

Comment: 追記を試してみたら出来ましたね。そう言えばコメントに書かれていたのは`reset_index()`をしていなかったのを見落としていました。それの有無が対になっていれば良いということでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい、ご指摘のとおり、set_indexをした後に、reset_index()を記述されていたので、両方とってみた次第です！追記したコードを正として、実データに応用してみようと思います！

Answer (score 0):

そのままだとグラフ化しにくいので, 転置を行い, カラム名を `'Group'`から持ってきます

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   '購入数A': [150, 300, 100, 50, 300],
                   '購入数B': [500, 900, 350, 100, 300],
                   '購入数C': [1000, 390, 100, 300, 300],
                   '購入数D': [800, 400, 370, 800, 100],
                   '購入数E': [200, 50, 500, 350, 300]})

df = df.set_index('Group').T
```

あとは DataFrameの plotメソッドで可能です

```py
# 日本語フォントの指定
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Takao', 'IPAexGothic', 'IPAPGothic', 'Noto Sans CJK JP']

#df.plot.bar()   # 全部まとめる場合
df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(2, 3))   # 別々に表示の場合
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！上でkunifさまがアドバイスいただいた内容を参考に、アレンジしたコードをトップに追記しました。（set_index、reset_indexをとったものです）こちらはseabornですが、df.plotと、dataframeからダイレクトに棒グラフを作成することもできるのですね。いろいろな方法がありとても勉強になります。（色々あるので、どれを使うかを判断する力も必要ですよね、、）